# requiring an ActiveRecord model without having to require the entire class diagram, for active_record_spec_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, rails-activerecord

I want to set up an `active_record_spec_helper` for my Rails tests so that I can test my models  without having to set up the entire Rails environment - as laid out by Corey Haines in his [excellent blog post on the subject](http://articles.coreyhaines.com/posts/active-record-spec-helper/).

(I know that preloaders like Spring or Guard go part of the way towards fixing this problem, but I agree with Corey's argument that this is "really just a band-aid over the real problem".)

So I've set up my spec helper and other files as laid out in Corey's blog post and [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/coreyhaines/2068977) - but my problem is exactly as I describe it in [my comment](https://gist.github.com/coreyhaines/2068977#comment-1344620) on that same gist:

Basically, the associations between my models mean that to test a single model, I have to `require` so many other model files that it negates the point of using `active_record_spec_helper` in the first place.

E.g. if I want to test `comment.rb` but my comment `belongs_to :post`, then I have to require `post` as well as `comment` to make my tests work. But then `Post` may have other associations, e.g. `belongs_to :user; has_many :drafts`, so I have to require `user` and `drafts` as well just to test `Comment`... then `user` and `drafts` have associations too, and so on until I end up loading practically every model in my class diagram.

(If this doesn't make sense, I gave a more detailed explanation in [the comment](https://gist.github.com/coreyhaines/2068977#comment-1344620).)

Is it possible to work around this and avoid having to `require` all those extraneous model files? Or is there something conceptual that I'm missing - should I be avoiding linking all my models in this giant web, or is it unavoidable?

Or is it just not worth the effort and should I stick with letting `rails_helper` load the whole environment?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're missing anything conceptual and I think having models linked in a giant web through associations is natural in large Rails applications.

As for workarounds to this problem, I can think of several:

- Stub the models being depended on when testing the models that directly depend on them. This will eliminate the need to load or stub the models indirectly depended on.
- Turn on autoloading. While this will slow things down, it's not the same as starting up all of Rails
- Instead of just listing your dependencies as comments at the top of your models as Corey suggested, express them in Ruby code. This code can be a no-op in production, but in test you can configure the code to either require or stub the dependencies as you wish.

Comment: How can I turn on autoloading without loading the entire Rails app? Is it somewhere in ActiveSupport?

Comment: The Ruby autoload mechanism is not sufficient by itself and I'm not sure if/how the Rails mechanism built on top of it can be separately called. I probably shouldn't have been so glib in describing that option. If you can't find something in a Rails gem that's usable as is, you can read about the capability at http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/, for example and perhaps roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using FactoryGirl.  Please [see my gist for details](https://gist.github.com/codenamev/8aee0412b10f9e41da999edf21da62ce).

Using the `factory_girl_require_helper.rb`, you can do something like this at the top of your test:

```
require_factory_and_model_for(:comment)
```

That will auto-load any associated models that are dependent on the `Comment` based on the factory you have defined for it.